# im trying create a lua dll in C but the GCC is saying " undefined reference to `luaL_checknumber' "

Tags: c, gcc, lua

I've been having problems creating my native Lua library for some time now. I've seen several tutorials teaching how to do it, following step by step, but it always gives these errors.

About the error it says there are three undefined references but i'm pretty sure all the headers are in the project.

This is my C code:

```
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include <stdio.h>


static int l_mult50(lua_State *L) {
    double number = luaL_checknumber(L, 1);
    lua_pushnumber(L, number*50);
    return 1;
}

int luaopen_libnativefunc(lua_State *L) {
    static const struct luaL_Reg nativeFuncLib [] =
    {
        {"mult50", l_mult50},
        {NULL, NULL}
    };

    luaL_register(L, "nativelib", nativeFuncLib);
    return 1;
}
```

I did exactly the same as in a tutorial I saw, because I wanted at least the compile to dll step to work.

how do i compile:

```
gcc nativefunc.c -c -fpic
```

```
gcc nativefunc.o -shared -o libnativefunc.dll
```

my folders:
[image: 1]

Comment: You need to *link* with the actual Lua libraries.

Comment: You still have to link in the lua dll - `-llua` or whatever.

Comment: Are you on Windows and trying to follow tutorials written for Linux?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, most say it's just change the .so to .dll if is windows

Comment: That's not the only difference, as the other commenters alluded to. Try following a tutorial designed for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need it to compile your own C library for LOVE (because the code is exactly the same as in one of the tutorials on LOVE forums). You forgot to include "lua51.dll" in the GCC command. First, you need to go to the folder where you installed "LOVE", borrow the DLL file from there and place it in the folder with your project (where your "nativefunc.c" is).

Then you can run batch file with the following commands:

```
gcc nativefunc.c -c -fpic
gcc -L./ -llua51 nativefunc.o -shared -o libnativefunc.dll
```

Also, don't forget to check that the DLL uses the same processor architecture as your GCC compiler (x64 or x86). If it doesn't, the DLL will be incompatible with the program and you are going to receive the error: "%1 is not a valid Win32 application".